# NY Part-Resident Income allocation

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax

Let's say I moved out of NY state on June 30th, 2022 (exactly half year NY resident) but I continue to work for same employer but in a different state. (New state I moved to, doesn't have state income tax). If I receive commission towards end of the year (when I was not a NY resident); is it true that I still need to allocate half of W2 box 16 wage to NY? (NY requires everything to be reported on box 16 even though I was a resident only for 6 months) . For example, Let's say my total wage was 60K (50k + 10K commission ; and commission pay date is in December ) , when I use IT-203-B schedule A to allocate NY wage, NY portion would be 30K, even though my pay stubs show a total of 25K end of June (NY resident income) ?

Comment: What is the commission for?

Comment: commission is based on the projects we completed.

Comment: Through the year, right?

Comment: Yes; but say my pay was not consistent through the year (for example I received pay hike after I moved). How do I allocate the pay if the pay was not consistent?

Comment: You don't? *Do not use this schedule for income based on the volume of business transacted*

Answer (score 1):

See Form IT-203, Nonresident and Part-Year Resident Income Tax Return. Essentially, you pay NY (and city, if applicable) taxes for income received during the period you were resident, possibly plus tax on income from NY state sources during the period you weren't resident (subject to NY standard deduction).

(Websearching "ny tax partial year" finds this form's instructions, plus articles on this topic from other sources.)

Comment: To allocate the Wages, I believe I need to fill out 'IT-203-B income allocation' form. But what if my pay was not consistent throughout the year even though same employer? How do I allocate the % amount to NY using T-203-B income allocation form?